# DirectShow .NET custom graph

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I am trying to build a custom graph filter and I am having problems.

I am using the C# DirectShow.NET lib

I am reading a file with vc1 video and dts audio. i add the source filter to the graph, it works fine, i can also add the splitter filter (using lav splitter), but when i try to connect the file source filter to the lav splitter, it fails.

and it fails, because it doesn't find any input pin on the splitter ... i know that output pins can be dynamic, but the input pin should be there right ?

this is the code

```
_graphBuilder = (IGraphBuilder)new FilterGraph();
_dsRotEntry = new DsROTEntry((IFilterGraph)_graphBuilder);

LogInfo("Adding source filter...");
int hr = _graphBuilder.AddSourceFilter(_inputFilePath, _inputFilePath, 
    out _fileSource);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

IPin pinSourceOut = DsFindPin.ByDirection(_fileSource, PinDirection.Output, 0);
if (pinSourceOut == null)
{
    LogError("Unable to find source output pin");
};

IBaseFilter lavSplitter = CreateFilter(LAV_SPLITTER);
if (lavSplitter == null)
{
    LogError("LAV Splitter not found");
};

hr = _graphBuilder.AddFilter(lavSplitter, "LAV Splitter");
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

bool result = TryConnectToAny(pinSourceOut, lavSplitter);
if (!result)
{
    LogError("Unable to connect FileSource with LAV Splitter");
}
```

and

```
private bool TryConnectToAny(IPin sourcePin, IBaseFilter destinationFilter)
{
    IEnumPins pinEnum;
    int hr = destinationFilter.EnumPins(out pinEnum);
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
    IPin[] pins = { null };
    while (pinEnum.Next(pins.Length, pins, IntPtr.Zero) == 0)
    {
        int err = _graphBuilder.Connect(sourcePin, pins[0]);
        if (err == 0)
            return true;
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pins[0]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that input pin does exist, and what fails is the connection itself. `err` holds error code to possibly explain the problem. If it is unable to make the connection, `TryConnectToAny` returns false the same way as if there were no input pins on the filter at all.